# param not found: generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im trying to build my 3rd model(result) along with 2nd model ( generator). I call the result form from my Generator show.html.erb and when i clicked the submit button in the form  i get this error `param not found: generator`

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
    resources :generators 
    resources :results
  end
```

**Generator show.html.erb**

```
...
        <legend><strong>Binding Time Analysis</strong></legend>
    <%= render "results/form" %>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**Result.controller**

```
def new
    @result=Result.new
  end

  # GET /results/1/edit

  # POST /results
  # POST /results.json TGATGAACATCATGATGAGGTGATGACATCACATCATTGACTGATGCATCATGATG
  def create
    @result = @generator.build_result(result_params)
    @result=@result.generate_result(result_params)
    @generator.result.save
    redirect_to user_generators_path
  end

def result_params
      params.require(:result).permit(:ncbi_ref_seq,:genome_seq,:genome_sample,:binding_times,:amp_frags,:seqpos1,:seqpos2)
    end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :generators
  has_many :results, :through=>:generators
```

**Generator.rb**

```
class Generator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :result , :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :choice, :primer_length, :random_primer_generated, :generator_id
```

**Result.rb**

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :generator_id,:ncbi_ref_seq,:genome_seq, :genome_sample
   belongs_to :generator
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@generator.build_result,:url =>user_generator_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :id => @generator.id),:html =>{:method=>:put}) do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:ncbi_ref_seq ,nil, placeholder: 'Accession Number')%>
  </p>

  <p id="highlight"><font size ="5">
        OR  
  </font></p>

  <p id="FASTA">
    <strong><font size ="3">Paste your sequence here: ( FASTA format ) :</font></strong> 
    <%= text_area_tag(:genome_seq,nil,size: "50x10",placeholder: 'Input your sequence here')%>
 </p>

  <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">
    <%= submit_tag 'Analyze' %>
<% end %>
```

**Generator.controller generator_params**

```
def generator_params
        params.require(:generator).permit(:generator_id,:primer_length,:choice,:random_primer_generated,:no_A,:no_T,:no_G,:no_C,:user_seq)
    end
```

Comment: `resources :users do`
    `resources :generators `
    `resources :results`
  `end`

Comment: We need to see your `result_params` method from your ResultsController. This seems like a `strong_parameters` issue.

Comment: What im trying to do is just to create current_user.generator.result

Comment: Where are you defining the instance variable `@generator` used in your `create` method?