# Rails console returned result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi guys i tried rails console>>User.all and it gives me

```
[1m←[36mUser Load (10.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users"←[0m
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, provider: "facebook", uid: "557863943", name: "Brian Choo", created_at: "2013-1
2-13 12:19:53", updated_at: "2013-12-13 12:19:53">]>
```

From the result , does it mean that there's something wrong with it ? how come the ActiveRecord::Relation is there and there are []'s too. I don't remember having those usually.

Comment: `[1m←[36mUser Load (10.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT` this is non-ascii color

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby on Rails 4

```
User.all
```

returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` (provided `User` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, of course).
This has changed since RoR 3.x, where `all` returned `Array`. 
So, the answer is: no, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: oh. Ok thanks. But however my program is returning me null values when i 'm trying to return result which belongs to Generator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522514/param-not-found-generator?noredirect=1#comment30684913_20522514

Answer (score 1):

That is as expected. Rails returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` scope object with an array of `Users`.